# Paypal sandbox checkout error

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working with paypal integration using checkout.js It was working fine till last day.

Now even in the test environment it is not working. It returns 400 error.
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Production is working fine , issue is only with sandbox.

What is causing the issue? Is sandbox down?

status page shows sandbox is operational

Comment: I experienced the same problem before and its their way of screwing with  developers. Their checkout.js API works fine in Production but not in Sandbox. 
Paypal is concentrating on Braintree SDK these days , I think they are trying to deprecate the checkout.js sandbox feature. By the way Braintree is Paid!!